# jquery get previous div inside row

Tags: jquery, selector, closest

How can I get the values from the previous div inside the row?

```
echo '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 80px; height: 4px;">
            <input type="text" value="'.$item['SAP'].'" class="form-control input-sm">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 330px;">
            <input type="text" value="'.$item['Name'].'" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 300px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left:  0px; width: 40px; height: 4px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="'.$item['SAP'].'" value="0" style="width: 40px">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 40px; height: 4px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                <span class="AddQuantity glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>`enter code here`
```

I am using this:

```
            $('.AddQuantity').on('click', function () {
                var currentVal = $(this).closest('row').find('.form-control input-sm').val();
                alert(currentVal);
            });
        });
```

But it's not working

Comment: What "values" are you looking to get?

Comment: I have an input and a plus button. I want to add 1 to the input when I click the button. But de number of rows depend on the number of products. So I want do this dynamic.

Comment: You want to add 1 to every element with that class, or just the previous one. You have to be as specific as possible

Comment: Thank you. This I very easy if I had only one row with an input and one button. But imagine that instead of just one row I have a variable number of rows. For each product there is a row with this input and button. I want to click in one button and add a value to the input on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot dots before classes names `input-sm` and `row`.

Also, you don't need `space` between `.form-control` and `.input-sm`, because `space` is using for descendant elements search

```
var currentVal = $(this).closest('.row').find('.form-control.input-sm').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the previous one, find the closest DIV wrapper, get the previous DIV, and then find the input :

```
$(this).closest('div').prev('div').find('.form-control.input-sm').val();
```

or for all of them (adding 1)

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.form-control.input-sm').val(function(_,v) {
    return (+v) + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is not quite right I don't think.

`$(this).closest(".row")...[etc]` should work

`row` is going to look for an element called `row`, not the *class name* of an element.